# kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut not affecting UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, catransition

I have a cycle of images I am trying to fade from one to the other using `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut` so its not so abrupt. My `UIImageView` is receiving the objects from a MutableArray. Here is the code I am using to achieve the fade affect.

```
 imageViewContainer = [UIView new];
imageViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 620);
imageViewContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view1 addSubview:imageViewContainer];
for (int i = 0; i < [homescreenPictureArray count]; i++) {
    homescreenPictureView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 620)];
    homescreenPictureView.animationImages = homescreenPictureArray;
    homescreenPictureView.animationDuration = 15;
    [homescreenPictureView setAlpha:1.0f];
    homescreenPictureView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [imageViewContainer.layer addAnimation:pictureDisolve forKey:nil];
    [imageViewContainer addSubview:homescreenPictureView];

    pictureDisolve = [CATransition animation];
    pictureDisolve.duration = 1.0f;
    pictureDisolve.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    pictureDisolve.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [homescreenPictureView.layer addAnimation:pictureDisolve forKey:@"imageViewContainer"];
    [homescreenPictureView startAnimating];
```

I receive no errors when compiling yet its not affecting the images. Clarification on why its not working would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The transition type you're using is wrong. You need to use `kCATransitionFade`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `key` value. for example `@"subviews"`.
it defines, when and what will be transitioned.

```
pictureDisolve = [CATransition animation];
    pictureDisolve.duration = 1.0f;
    pictureDisolve.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    pictureDisolve.type = kCATransition;
    [homescreenPictureView.layer addAnimation:pictureDisolve forKey:@"subviews"];
```

Comment: So I fiddled around with your answer a bit. I'm not quite sure if I'm missing something obvious here. I updated the code so you can see whats going on entirely. Any thoughts as to why its not effecting it would be appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

So I'm working on a different project now but I figured I would give a good example of the kCATransitionFade for anyone who views this in the future.

`-(void) fadeIn {

```
view1.image = background1;
view2.image = background2;

CATransition *fadeIn = [CATransition animation];
fadeIn.duration = 2.0f;
fadeIn.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
fadeIn.type = kCATransitionFade;
fadeIn.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:fadeIn forKey:nil];
view1.hidden = YES;
view2.hidden = NO;

NSLog(@"Image 1");
```

}

-(void) fadeOut {

```
view1.image = background1;
view2.image = background2;

CATransition *fadeIn = [CATransition animation];
fadeIn.duration = 2.0f;
fadeIn.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
fadeIn.type = kCATransitionFade;
fadeIn.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:fadeIn forKey:nil];
view1.hidden = NO;
view2.hidden = YES;

NSLog(@"Image 2");
```

}
`

For my project I left it for use as [self fadeIn] or [self fadeOut] but if you would like you can combine them into  single function by calling

```
-(void) fadeFunction {

if (self.view == view1) {
    [self fadeIn];
} else {
    [self fadeOut];
}
```

}